# ASP.NET 3.5 Web Site stopped importing System namespace by default

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, namespaces

I have a VB Web Site project that has recently (and mysteriously) stopped importing the "System" namespace by default.

I'm having to either place an `Imports System` line at the top of each code behind, or preface everything with `System`, which is fairly annoying, not to mention redundant. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the `System` namespace back to being imported by default.

I've already checked to see that `WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config` contains the `<add namespace="System"/>` line--it does. That was my best lead.

I have references to several namespaces within the `System` namespace in the `<assemblies>` node (e.g. `System.Design`, `System.Web.Extensions` of my website's web.config. There is no `<namespaces>` node. This has not been changed recently.

I'm tearing my hair out. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have fixed itself as mysteriously as it broke in the first place. I'm not sure what I did, but it's working now. So it goes.

Comment: Sigh, I have the Same problem. But only in a few projects. Seems to be on .net 3.5 but 4.0 does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

Just been through this with a VB Web Project in VS 2013.

Lots of cases of the error from types in the System, System.Collections<sup>1</sup>, …

Turns out when copying a `<configSections>` element into the `web.config` (as part of adding some better logging) I'd copied the surrounding `<configuration>` element in as well.

Lots of weirdness followed. Was able to find issue when I found I could get the site to run and the IIS error page told me I had a configuration error.

Now to redo all the changes I had undone on my way to finding that….

---

<sup>1</sup> The wonders of legacy code maintenance.