# ASP.NET 3.5 Website missing namespaces in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-3.5

I have an issue that is very similar to this question:
[ASP.NET 3.5 Web Site stopped importing System namespace by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631477/asp-net-3-5-web-site-stopped-importing-system-namespace-by-default)

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 Website (not application) project in VB.NET that compiles fine Visual Studio 2008. When I open the project in Visual Studio 2012 (or 2010), I get some very weird errors that make it appear as if the System and System.Data namespaces are missing. In most cases, all of these errors are happening in the App_Code folder. In some instances, I can add an Imports System to the class and it fixes it. I expect this website to compile as soon as I opened it in VS 2012.

Here is sampling of the errors I am getting:

- `CommandType` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
- `DateTime` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
- `HttpContext` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
  protection level.

I believe VB.NET does do some implicit imports but it seems that I am missing them.

Edit: The site runs fine in IIS and does not produce any compile errors.

The compilation tag of my web.config file looks like:

```xml
<compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" batch="false">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
```

I have tried to add System and System.Data but it didn't help. It should be pulling from the default assemblies from the web.config file in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG. As I said before, this same solution (even though it's a web site project) builds in VS 2008.

Edit:

I have narrowed this down to several DLLs in my BIN folder which each individually are causing this error (if I add one of them back, the errors reappear). One of the trouble DLLs is Recaptcha.dll. There is nothing special about this DLL and it works fine in VS2008 and loads fine in IIS.

Comment: VS2012 worked for my VS2010 MVC project at first, then completely messed up a bunch of my files.  I googled it and there were some bugs that were yet to have been fixed at the time.  I don't recommend using it.

Comment: Rename your app_code folder to something else. VS 2010 and VS2012 no longer like having user code in that folder.

Comment: I had no issues with App_Code in 2010, but that was a website project.  I only received the errors you mention when I tried to upgrade to a Web Application Project.

Comment: This is a Web Site Project and not a Web Application Project. I cannot move the files outside of App_Code because they will not compile. I have another Web Site Project that I upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 (still .NET 3.5) and it worked fine. However that was C#. I want this project to remain as a Web Site Project.

Comment: Do you see System.Web.dll assembly (for example) referenced in your web site?

Comment: Could you post your web.config?  In particular the `<compilation>` section might be of help.

Comment: Yet another reason to not use web site "projects"

Comment: Just curious have you tryed starting a project of the same type in vs 2012 and comparing the section with yours from vs 2010 too see whats missing ? - this is prob the easiest way to find out if something wasn't moved / converted right.... hope this helps

Comment: Do you mind sharing the full list of DLL's that are causing the problem?

Comment: have you matched the assembly versions and tokens from C:\Windows\assembly\ ?

Comment: The DLLs are not in the GAC. I did not have to modify my web.config to fix the problem. Simply deleting these DLLs fixed the issue. The DLLs are Recaptcha.dll, APToolkitNET.dll, APWebGrb.dll (activePDF), AJAXControlToolkit.dll and an internal DLL. All of these individually create the errors. The odd part is the that the activePDF DLLs work on another upgraded VS2012 web site project except it's an IIS project (vs a file system project) and nothing special in the web.config.

Comment: Can you try creating a brand new Web Site project (without changing the default Web.config) and see if the error still occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference to a webservice in your website project? I have experienced problems when the reference to the webservice includes all the types from webservice. The is because the checkbox 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' is checked on the Service Reference Settings.

Comment: I thought this might have been the problem as well but it wasn't. I am going to try to start a new project to see if I can duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar issue with my views in asp.net MVC. In my case I had inadvertently duplicated a section in my configuration file. I think it was the

```
<system.web>
```

section which caused Visual Studio all manner of confusion - compilation worked fine, but I received unusual errors in the error list. Could be something similar? Check your web.config and your views web.config files for any duplicate sections?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issues several times.  Always turns out that we made some minor mistake inside our App Code (Class Objects) that the IDE doesn't like, but the compiler will compile and run without error.  A lot of time it is when we do a Method Signature like:

```
 Public Sub Foo (byval Parm1 as long, _
      byval Parm2 as long,
      byval Parm3 as long)
```

And we forget an "_" like my example above with Parm2.

They can be a real pain to track down.